# Convert MongoDB Script to NodeJS Script using ExpressJS Framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i have code mongodb like this

```
function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName){

    var sequenceDocument = db.counters.findAndModify({
       query:{_id: sequenceName },
       update: {$inc:{sequence_value:1}},
       new:true
    });

    return sequenceDocument.sequence_value;
 }

 db.corpusQuestion.find({"merchantId": NumberInt(2091)}).forEach(function(i){ 
  i._id = new ObjectId(); 
  i.merchantId = NumberInt(2093);
  i.temp_id = getNextSequenceValue("questionid");

  db.corpusAnswer.find({"merchantId": NumberInt(2091), "idQuestion": i.id}).forEach(function(crpAns){ 
   crpAns._id = new ObjectId();
   crpAns.idQuestion = i.temp_id; 
   crpAns.merchantId = NumberInt(2093); 
   db.corpusAnswer.insert(crpAns); 
  });

  i.id = i.temp_id
  db.corpusQuestion.insert(i); 
 });

 db.cosineTerm.find({"merchant_id": NumberInt(2091)}).forEach(function(i){ i._id = new ObjectId(); i.merchant_id = NumberInt(2093); db.cosineTerm.insert(i); });
 db.further.find({"merchant_id": "2091"}).forEach(function(i){ i._id = new ObjectId(); i.merchant_id = "2093"; db.further.insert(i); });
```

i want this mongodb script convert to nodejs script.. can u guys help me? :')
this code used for my project nlp-util..

Comment: See some examples at [MongoDB NodeJS Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/tutorials/main/) _and_
[Node.js & MongoDB - The CRUD Operations](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-video-nodejs--mongodb--the-crud-operations). May be try by yourself and post the specific problems you are facing.

Comment: More context is needed. What do you mean to convert to NodeJS script? Like you want to run the script via NodeJS or what?